# SSRS Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: reporting-services, sql-server-2012, runtime-error, business-intelligence

I'm working on a complex SSRS report that contains a number of subreport, with a total of five levels of nested sub-reports. This is a lot, but necessary due to the complicated nature of the top level report.

I've encountered an odd error with the last subreport I've added:

```
Warning 1   [rsErrorExecutingSubreport] An error occurred while executing the subreport 'ThingRateQuotaWrapper' (Instance: T0R0S0S1T0R0x0S0): Object reference not set to an instance of an object. C:\Users\mmxxxxxxx\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\ThingsReporting\ThingsReporting\Thing 2014 Consolidated Report.rdl  0   0
```

The problem here is that when I run the second level report (one of the reports contained in the top level "consolidated" report), everything works fine. But in the top level report, I get this unepected error.

The specific subreport mentioned is four levels down from the top report, so I would expected the second level report to fail if there was an issue, however as just mentioned that works perfectly.

In addition, the RDL and line number mentioned in the error message tells me nothing useful.

I've tried everything I can think of to solve this problem, including deleting, saving, re-inserting and configuring all the subreports from the ThingRateQuotaWrapper upwards. At this point I can think of nothing else to try that makes any sense.

How can a report fail because of a sub report four levels down, when other reports in between work correctly?

Anyone got any ideas or tips? I'm using SQL Server 2012 Business Intelligence and Visual Studio Premium 2012.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've solved this problem, however I don't entirely understand the solution so I welcome any comments which might expand on it.

My approach was to look through each expression in the set of reports and subreports that make up my consolidated report, looking for any that might fail for any reason. I discovered that the visibility expression for the tablix row which contains the ThingRateQuotaWrapper subreport had the dreaded red squiggly line beneath it.

I believe the cause of the field warning is that the visibility expressed used a dataset other than the primary dataset of the tablix. I reworked the tablix dataset to contain the required column to determine visibility of the subreport, then updated the visibility expression to use the new column in the primary dataset. This fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

This issue still impact SSRS in Visual Studio 2017 when renaming a sub-report.
Delete all the object in the \bin\ folder and VS will rebuild it without the error.

Comment: That didn't work for me. The subreport will run and now the subreport is just empty it just displays the report parameters I pass in and I still get this error.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, sub report's name had been changed (params and everything were correct) just name had been changed. Lead to this error.

Answer (score 0):

This tends to happen when you change the names on reports. I accomplished this by deleting the .data files in my project directory as this stores the cached data of your reports. Then restart visual studios and the problem should be resolved.
In short:

1. Delete .DATA files in directory
2. Restart Visual Studios

Hope this helps.
Thanks 
Gavin

Answer (score 0):

To anyone coming to this old thread, I had the exact same error message with the following configuration:

1. Main report (top parent level report) calls 5 sub report hierarchy deep
2. The sub report is crashing only when generating from the Main report. Everything is fine when calling from each sub report level (all!) including the sub report itself

**Pre-requisite explanation**

The business wants me to show either a Bar chart OR a textbox on a dedicated condition.
To avoid empty spaces produced by a ReportItem (my subReport outputing a bar chart) that is hidden, I usually put them inside a Tablix and manage the Row visibility. Like that, no empty spaces is generated !

**Old structure causing issue**

I have one tablix with two rows :

3. The first one contains my sub report outputting a bar chart
4. The second one contains a simple TextBox

The tablix's dataset is a dataset containing the Textbox's text value (and that's the key of the problem !)

**New structure fixing the issue**

I have now 2 tablix :

1. One tablix with a dummy dataset ("SELECT 1 as 'Dummy') associated to the tablix. This tablix calls the bar chart's sub report
2. A second tablix with the same dataset as before (containing the Textbox's text value)

**UPDATE 29.06.2022**

The solution described above worked without RowVisibility condition. As soon as I've added my expression it fails again :

```
=IIF(RowNumber("myDataSetName")=0, True, False)
```

Solution: replace by this condition instead :

```
=IIF(Count(Fields!MyFieldName.Value) = 0, True, False)
```

This produces the same : When there the SQL query returns no row, I want to hide it.
It's very strange that SSRS doesn't tell my expression is wrong somehow, and last but not least, it's very weird that the expression works in all report levels except from the Main report. Either an expression is wrong or not.
Looks like a bug in SSRS (SQL Server 2017...maybe it's fixed in SQL Server 2019)